# A mysterious MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, activerecord, codeigniter-2, mysql-5.5

I have the following relational tables by relation depicted as :

```
Table product(id(PK),name,type(FK),category(FK),brand(FK));

Table Specification (id(PK),name);

Table product_specification_m2m (id(PK),specification(FK),value);

Table speclist (id(PK),specification(FK),product_type(FK),listtype);
```

**And running this query for a product brings result as expected :**

```
select m2m.specification,sl.product_type,sl.listtype 
from product_specification_m2m m2m 
     left join specification s on  
     s.id = m2m.specification
     left join speclist sl on 
     sl.specification = m2m.specification
     where m2m.product=626 and sl.product_type=8 and listtype="short";

     +---------------+--------------+----------+
     | specification | product_type | listtype |
     +---------------+--------------+----------+
     |            98 |            8 | short    |
     |           100 |            8 | short    |
     +---------------+--------------+----------+
     2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But for any other product of **product_type=8** running this query brings 
an empty array ! :

```
select m2m.specification,sl.product_type,sl.listtype 
from product_specification_m2m m2m 
     left join specification s on  
     s.id = m2m.specification
     left join speclist sl on 
     sl.specification = m2m.specification
     where m2m.product=471 and sl.product_type=8 and listtype="short";

     0 rows in set (0.00 sec)

     For listtype="long" it mysteriously brings :
     +---------------+--------------+----------+
     | specification | product_type | listtype |
     +---------------+--------------+----------+
     |           135 |            8 | long     |
     +---------------+--------------+----------+
     1 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anyone please point me out the mystery (Or so dumb am I that after spending 3 hours too I can't find it !) going on here!

**EDIT :**

The speclist table takes some specification and classifies them for "short" list and "long" list. That's how I show them on a web page. The shortlist keeps 2/3 spec ids and long usually keeps 9/10 spec ids.

**To hilight things again :**

Each Product type has a set of Specifications.

Each product has a subset of specification of that type (to which the product and the specifications belong to)

and each product again has two subset of specifications categorized by "short and "long" in speclist table.

Comment: Please provide column types and also check for any spaces in long field. to test try listtype like "%short%"

Answer (score 0):

Exclude **m2m.product=471** from **WHERE** clause and check what products exists for that conditions: **sl.product_type=8 and listtype="short"**

You write that for "**listtype="long"** it mysteriously brings" an record. There is no mystery. You look for product 471 and You get it for **listtype="long"** so why You want get that product for  **listtype="short"**? I'm assuming It doesn't exists with this **listtype**

Comment: @edam Post an output for query without "m2m.product=471" condition please.

Comment: It just brings the whole set of specification that belong to sl.product_type=X ;

Comment: @edam Yes, of course. Now check if You have product=471 in that set.